# What control do I use to get a custom checked list box in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

[image]

I am looking for a control that will show a list of Layers with a checkbox toggling its visibility and a thumbnail for its preview.

What control do I use in c# win forms?
How to go about custom rendering the individual list cells?

In java I would have used a JTable and rendered each cell according to the type of each cell. How do I do the same in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) should do what you need.

Edit: In particular enable "Checkboxes" in the properties. You can look into [Owner Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx) for more rendering functionality.